# pandas keep rows with multiple delimiters

Tags: python, pandas

one text file with multiple columns for represntation just showing 2 columns and 5 rows original df has ~400,000 rows

```
col0 col1 
A1   info
A2   info1,info2
A3   info4,info1,info6
A4   info3,info10
A5   info7,info1,info2,info4,info9
```

What I would like to do is in there is a row where col1 has multiple elements keep the first element and remove rest of the elements expected output

```
col0 col1 
A1   info
A2   info1
A3   info4
A4   info3
A5   info7
```

for sanity check is it possible to output the rows that were modified in a separate text file?
example

file_with_rows_modified.txt will have

```
col0 col1
A2   info1,info2
A3   info4,info1,info6
A4   info3,info10
A5   info7,info1,info2,info4,info9
```

edit: these are flat strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
df.col1 = df.col1.str.split(',').str[0]


    col0    col1
0   A1      info
1   A2      info1
2   A3      info4
3   A4      info3
4   A5      info7
```

For your second question,

```
df[df.col1.str.split(',').str.len() >1]
```

will return all the rows that need to be edited so you can save the result into another df before modifying the dataframe

Comment: can you please tell me how did you load this into a df? the error i get is `NameError: name 'A1' is not defined` using jupyter notebook

Comment: Can you give more details? Load what into df? Even I am using Jupyter notebook

Comment: Can you please share how did you create the df?

Comment: I just copied the df you posted and then df = pd.read_clipboard()

Comment: I am using this `df_1 ={'col0': ['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5'],'col1': [text1, text2, text3, text4, text5]}` but unable to load it

Comment: You need df = pd.DataFrame({'col0': [], ..}) given that you have your info1, info2 etc stored in text1, text2 already